# Converting GraphViz/Dot to Powerpoint Graph

Tags: graph, powerpoint, graphviz, dot

I'm trying to get from a GraphViz graph to a graph in Powerpoint. But, when it's inside of Powerpoint I would like to be able to edit the individual nodes, edges, boundaries. This means exporting the GraphViz as an image file won't work.

Does anyone know any path to get from GraphViz to Powerpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using LibreOffice. I've tested the process with LibreOffice 7.0.4.2.

1. Export your graph as SVG in **Graphviz** (`-Tsvg`).
2. Create a presentation in **LibreOffice**: File → New → Presentation
3. Delete the elements in the slide (title & body boxes).
4. Import the SVG file: Insert → Image
5. Once the image is inserted, select it by left-clicking on it.
6. Open the context menu by right-clicking on the image and choose Break.
7. Save the presentation as .pptx: File → Save As... →  Choose the file type .pptx in the dialog.
8. Open the .pptx in **PowerPoint**.
9. Select all the image components and copy them to your actual presentation.
10. Edit the image.

(Of course, you can do 9. and 10. in reverse order.)

Comment: That looks exciting. I'm pretty busy right now but I'll try this in a couple of days!

Comment: @greedybuddha, did you try this?

Comment: Hi @haba713 . That is the closest I've seen! The key point seems to be the "break" operation on the image which actually does separate the nodes, text, and lines into separate objects. Those objects aren't linked like I would like them to be, and this isn't perfect but it's better than nothing. Until a better solution comes around this at least gets most of the way there and I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for trying this method.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate .emf (Enhanced Metafile) images from .dot files using GraphViz on Windows.  You can import the .emf file into your PowerPoint presentation and then ungroup it (several times) to break it down into the individual shapes.

This is good, but unfortunately the edges of your graph do not get turned into connectors.  Instead, they are pictures of lines, so they don't reroute when you move any of the nodes of your graph around.

Comment: Exporting to emf and importing in PowerPoint does not work for me, the nodes are suddenly to small for the text they contain.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the XML structure of a .PPTX file, you could export your GraphViz graph as an SVG -- which is in reality a text format -- then parse it and emit the XML needed to create the .PPTX file.  A difficult method though, I know.

Like all of the Microsoft "open document" formats, the .PPTX is really just a ZIP file that contains many elements, the XML describing the graph being one of them.

Comment: Thanks @TomServo. This answer is technically possible but seems practically out of reach to do correctly without a large amount of effort and time. It's true though, so if no one else answers for a while I'll accept this.

Comment: @greedybuddha Without a doubt this is hard.  I have semi-parsed SVG before to extract certain sizing elements, but to parse and re-emit it is a tall order.  I work at a place where "it's impossible" can get one fired.... so thought I'd share something close.  ;)

Comment: @greedybuddha If you have Office 365, subscription version, and it's been updated recently, you can directly import SVG files and in some cases, ungroup them. SVG support is fairly new to PPT, so it may not support everything SVG is capable of. If you don't have this version but would like to test it, I'd be happy to try importing and ungrouping a file or two.  Post them on Dropbox or the like and pop the link in here.

Comment: Thanks @SteveRindsberg, I don't have Office 365, and it doesn't work in my Powerpoint 2016 for Mac. I'll see if I can buy an account on Office 365 to test this.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg. I broke down and got an Office 365 subscription but still no luck. In the online version I upload a svg and it says "Sorry we only support jpg ... files". If I use the desktop version it just comes up with a picture not recognized icon. Transferring the saved desktop version with the svg to the online version also doesn't work.

Comment: After further research. It looks like svg support in Powerpoint is essentially in an alpha state. It is only available on certain online subscription versions, only supports limited svg files, and certain svg files will crash Powerpoint. So the direct svg to powerpoint is probably available next year after they debug it more

Comment: It's a pity it didn't work out better for you, but if you have examples of SVGs that don't work as expected or that crash PPT reproducibly, I can get them to the people at MS who're working on SVG support. If you'd like me to do that, please upload them to dropbox/onedrive or the like and post the link here. Thanks!

Comment: As an explanation as to why I haven't accepted this like I said I would above I would like to reiterate that while technically possible it would really be writing a fairly difficult library that needs to understand and translate several different formats. Way beyond the scope of most people, and out of the time constraints of most others. Given that I don't think this really gives an answer that even a profecient technical person could use.